# How to dynamically split tables when they move out of view (height) - CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to dynamically split tables when they move out of view (height).
Is there any way to do it with CSS or JavaScript?
Problem and solution needed is visible in picture below.

[Problem and solution needed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CscB.png)

Comment: Your picture suggests a design that is not a typical CSS `display`. You may need to use jQuery's `.height()` method *(or vanilla `Element.getBoundingClientRect().height`)*, so you can know when to continue your lists into the next column. You can use `display:flex;`, or floated `<div>`s that have widths, or even a table to create the columns.

Comment: Are the width and height of the cells fixed? Do you have to use `table` for the html or can is using `div` allowed?

Comment: by using  - jQuery Plugin For Newspaper Column Layout - Columnizer https://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Plugin-For-Newspaper-Column-Layout-Columnizer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got very interested in your project and found a solution that works.
i think this is what u wanted.

by using - jQuery Plugin For Newspaper Column Layout

[jQuery Plugin For Newspaper Column Layout](https://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Plugin-For-Newspaper-Column-Layout-Columnizer.html)

*but if the window size change you have to refresh the page to adjust tables height.*

```js
// Create table dynamically 
var i, j;
 var table = "";
 for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
   table += `<table data-id="` + i + `" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="head">` + i + ` Table</td>
   </tr>
   `;
   for (j = 1; j < i * 20; j++) {
     table += `<tr>
    <td>` + j + ` </td>
    <td>` + j + ` </td>
    <td>` + j + ` </td>
    <td>` + j + ` </td>
   </tr>`
   }
   table += `</table>`;
 }
 document.getElementById("npcolumns").innerHTML = table

// columnize script
 $(function() {
   var hiht = $(window).height() - 50;
   console.log(hiht);
   $('.npcolumns').columnize({
     width: 230,
     height: hiht,
     columns: 5,
     buildOnce: true,
     doneFunc: function() {
       $('<tr><td colspan="4" class="head continue"></td></tr>').insertBefore('table > tbody.split');
       $("table").each(function() {
         var curTable = $(this);
         var tableHead = $(curTable).attr('data-id');
         var cell = $(this).find("td.continue");
         $(cell).html(tableHead + " Table Continue");
       });
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
table {
  border: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

table td.head {
  border: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

table td {
  border: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Newspaper-Column-Layout-Columnizer/src/jquery.columnizer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="npcolumns" class="npcolumns"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```